# How do I delete files in different directory after Clean in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, project

I am working on some projects with Visual Studio 2005.  We are auto-generating some source code in pre-build and the auto-generated files are going to the same directory as the rest of the source code in the projects.  Now, I want to delete the auto-generated files on clean.  I know all about the "Extensions to Delete on Clean" option in the Project Properties.  But, it only deletes from the intermediate and build output directories.  I've tried to put "..*.ref" and "$(InputDir)*.ref" in this property and it does nothing.  Any ideas?